# How can I define my Custom Annotation to use a subset of target elements?

Tags: java, annotations

**Question:**

Is it possible to target multiple element types? (More than one, less than all)

**Details:**

I'm trying create an annotation that is only acceptable on Methods and Fields.

I know if I don't specify the `@Target` annotation I can use my custom annotation on all elements. However, I want compile time safety on element types that conflict with my logic.

In **C#/.NET**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    ...
```

**Java Attempts**

**Multiple Target Annotations:**

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface MyAnnotation
{
```

*Compiler Error:*

> MyAnnotation.java:8: error: duplicate annotation

**OR'd Values:**

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD | ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface MyAnnotation
{
```

*Compiler Error:*

> MyAnnotation.java:7: error: bad operand types for binary operator '|'

**Annotation Array**

```
@Targets({@Target(ElementType.METHOD),@Target(ElementType.FIELD)})
public @interface MyAnnotation
{
```

*Compiler Error:*

> MyAnnotation.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
>   @Targets({@Target(ElementType.METHOD),@Target(ElementType.FIELD)})
>     ^symbol: class Targets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java - The input is an array of ElementTypes. To define array values within an annotation, we comma separate the values within curly braces:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```